# Why does LinearLayout instance.getLayoutParams look to have a wrong class?

Tags: java, android

If I declare `LinearLayout linearLayout` and look at `linearLayout.getLayoutParams()`, it gives me `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, not `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

So I have to use the repeating (and thus bad) style construction of:

```
int lm = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin?
```

Do I really have to use it, if I want to reach margins, for example?

Is it my misunderstanding of Android or Java, or both or something else?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think your understanding about 'LayoutParams' is incorrect. A view's (or layout's) `LayoutParams` must be an instance of 'the parent view's LayoutParams'.

For example, here's an LinearLayout in RelativeLayout. That LinearLayout's LayoutParams must be RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. This thing enables us to set the attributes properly, like 'centerInParent' and etc.

When you call `getLayoutParams()`, that returns various instance of LayoutParams that matches to parent ViewGroup type. As a result, we need to cast the type of a view's LayoutParams repeatedly when calling `getLayoutParams()`.

Comment: Sorry, the type returning by linearLayout.getLayoutParams has nothing in common with the class of layout that contains that linearLayout. As for convenience, giving me the parent class' LayoutParams is senseless - if I need it, I could cast linearLayout to ViewsGroup and take its getLayputParams and have them universal. But Android gives me *only* ViewsGroup.LayoutParams.

Comment: Because It is ambiguous, it can't be returned specific type of LayoutParams while it is not a generic-type. The system can't know what type is. Your question is senseless to me.

Comment: If linearLayout has class of LinearLayout, the function linearLayout.getLayoutParams is that of the class LinearLayout and could easily return the class LinearLayout.LayoutParams. Where is the error?

Comment: No no. that's wrong thought. getLayoutParams just returns the field of LinearLayout instance and the field's type is declared as ViewGroup.LayoutParams initially. That's the reason of returning type of the method is ViewGroup.LayoutParams.

Comment: But that field (private or protected) in the  LinearLayout instance has without any doubt the class of LinearLayout.LayoutParams. Because after casting this type I see fields that are not present in  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.Interesting..

Comment: But the thought of analyzing the private fields of both classes is interesting. I'll try it tomorrow. (It is late even for me. And you hava a morning probably? let's go sleep)

Comment: Yes. If the LinearLayout's parent is LinearLayout, you can cast the field to LinearLayout.LayoutParams and more fields will be available. But that can't be casted permanently but only possible with referencing time. It is already declared with type ViewGroup.LayoutParams in os source code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7151/discussion-between-gangnus-and-lulumeya)

Comment: You were right. But sorry, it was not you, who explained me so that I understood. So, you have the answer check and he has the bounty.

Answer (score 8):

---

Just to put it in a very straight way:

**Please keep in mind that when you get the LayoutParams of a view, their class is determined by the class of the parent view of this view**.

This implies one very important fact:

You have to cast the LayoutParams of a View because you can not know beforehand what is the class of the parent. So, if *view*'s parent is a LinearLayout, it's *LayoutParams* will be of type *LinearLayout.LayoutParams* and **STILL you have to cast it to this type!**

---

I am not sure of the source code and how it goes. But it is very logical since RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, for example has properties such as ABOVE and BELOW which are not found in a LinearLayout.LayoutParams. And these params are actually dependent on the parent.

Comment: The protected field mLayoutParams that is used to give the result of this function, belongs to the View itself, not to its parent. The returning values, for example, margins, belong to this very View. The parent can by any type, the function result is always of ViewsGroup.LayoutParams class, not depending on the class of the parent. The function exists for the root layout, too, and it doesn't have parents, the screen is its parent. Why do you think that their class is determined by the parent? I don't see any sense in that thought - everything is against it.

Comment: I am not sure of the source code and how it goes. But it is very logical since RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, for example has properties such as ABOVE and BELOW which are not found in a LinearLayout.LayoutParams. And these params are actually dependent on the parent.

Comment: I see now. And because for different parents the fields could be different, I get the reference for params of the most primitive parent possible and later cast it to the class, that I know, will content all fields I need. Badly complicated, but it has sense.  ---  lulumeia said it to me earlier, but your explanation was understandable. Thank you, and have the jackpot :-)

Comment: But the answer check I'll give to the first answerer. I hope, no offence will be taken?

Comment: yeah sure! he said it right but I donno why! but his comments seemed as if he is not sure of his answer.. I intended to delete my answer later. Anyway thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7164/discussion-between-gangnus-and-sherif-elkhatib)

Answer (score 2):

You don't cast LinearLayout.LayoutParams to LinearLayout.LayoutParams. That makes no sense. Also it's not clear if `linearLayout` in your code is an instance variable... Either way, you can simply reference LayoutParams inside of a View that extends from some type of View to get that View's LayoutParams. For example, if you're inside of a class that extends from RelativeLayout, then

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(200, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

gets you `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. Otherwise, you'll need to qualify the `LayoutParams` you're looking for. To get/apply LinearLayout LayoutParams, you simply need

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams();
```

**EDIT**

`linearLayout.getLayoutParams()` returns the `layoutParams` that you supplied when you called `setLayoutParams`, so first make sure you do that. Then once you've done that, you simply need to cast the `LayoutParams` that were returned to the `LayoutParams` you set it to. so

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams()
```

Also, why do you need to get the params like this? What are you looking to accomplish ultimately? I ask because there may be an easier way to do what you're trying to do...

In effect, the answer to your question is YES, you need to cast the LayoutParams you get from getLayoutParams because that's a method derived from the View class which returns the superclass of LayoutParams which is ViewGroup.LayoutParams which, because of polymorphism, can be casted to the type you know it to be.

Comment: @Gangnus i dont know what you're talking about. There's no such thing as LinearLayout.LayoutParams.rightMargin. You simply call params.setMargins(int, int, int, int).

Comment: Sorry, I missed three letters in the function's name

Comment: +1 for the help in finding errors in the start variant of the question. Thank you. But please, if you'll help with the question further, make other answer - the question changed significantly.

Comment: Ehm. So, it is for *my* convenience? I am terribly sorry, but could you kindly say why it is convenient? An example would be enough.

Comment: The LayoutParams are useful when I have to change some Layout parametres that I can't reach by layout instance directly. I am *not* talking about *creation* of LayoutParams or previous setting. get-change-set. And in one line it is even shorter: get reference-change. This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Eclipse and just using the Eclipse 'Organise Imports' option to import Android libraries? If so, there's a few different libraries called LayourParams, Eclipse seems to be importing the framelayout one and not the linearlayout one like you need.

So just change the imports at the top of your class.

Comment: In the class I use ViewGroups.getLayoutParams and LinearLayout.getLayoutParams. I can't put in the import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams instead of import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams. Could I somehow use both?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the LinearLayout Params object from the LinearLayout itself. You can create a new one by yourself.

```
// Set up the height and width of the layout, you can set FILL_PARENT 
// or even WRAP_CONTENT
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
// Set up your margins
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Now use this `lp` object on your LinearLayout object instance

```
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: If you want to read leftMargin, you don't need to set a new params.  Even more, even if you need to *set* leftMargin, you don't want really to erase all other layout params.