# why do I need = (class) ... when I already declared the class?

Tags: java, objective-c

I'm not very familiar with the syntax and rules in Java so here is a quick question: why I have to write:

```
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
```

but I can't write:

```
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
```

In Obj-C, I only need to write the

```
UIScrollView* abc = (UIScrollView*) [self.view viewWithTag:(1)];
```

when the object returned from `[self.view viewwithtag:(1)]` is not in the expected class for `abc` (in this case it is in `UIView`).

Does the same logic apply to Java? If that is true, that means the object returned from `layout.getLayoutParams()` does not belong to the class `LayoutParams` and that is kind of weird.

So is my assumption correc or does Java have different rules?

Comment: what type is `layout`? and what type does its `getLayoutParams()` return?

Comment: what exactly is `layout.getLayoutParams();` returning? Is it an object of class `LayoutParams` or a sub-class of `LayoutParams`?

Comment: You could write it just the way you did with Objective C - IF the method returned a reference of type LayoutParams.  You have to cast because it doesn't.

Comment: You should ALWAYS specify what method you're talking about. If it's in a library, link to the documentation. If it's your own code, provide its declaration as well as relevant bits of the types involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. `getLayoutParams` must be returning a class that is not a sub-class of `LayoutParams`. Either the method name is poorly named or maybe there are two different `LayoutParams` classes in different packages. You should investigate what the return type is and confirm that it will always be a sub-class of the `LayoutParams` you are using otherwise you risk a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
```

Here you are typecasting any Object returned by `layout.getLayoutParams();` to an instance of `LayoutParams` type . This is called narrowing conversion. If `getLayoutParams();` returns an instance of class `LayoutParams` or its subclass, then this will work or it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You don't need to.

The only case in which you would need this is if `getLayoutParams()` returns a more general type and you're trying to narrow it. If that's the case, then that method's name is very misleading - but it has nothing to do with the syntax of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed write

```
 LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
```

if `layout.getLayoutParams()` declares to return a result of type `LayoutParams`, or a subclass of `LayoutParams`. However, it will not work if the declares to returns a super class (or interface) of `LayoutParams`, even if it actually is returning a `LayoutParams` instance. In that case, you will need to `cast` it to `LayoutParams`:

```
 LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)layout.getLayoutParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

If return type of`layout.getLayoutParams()` method is `LayoutParams` then

```
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
```

This will work fine.

But if the return type is general(Suppose an interface or super class of `LayoutParams` but it acually returns the object of `LayoutParams` ) in that case you have to type cast as **auto down casting is not possible in java and you have to explicitly cast**.

```
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is as you said: If the result is different than the expected class, you have to change it per `(class)` .
In your case, I believe that `getLayoutParams()` returns ViewGroup.LayoutParams, so you have to do the `(class)` change.
Here is an explanation to the [LayoutParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942415/why-does-linearlayout-instance-getlayoutparams-look-to-have-a-wrong-class)

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb here, but I'm guessing you're talking about [`View.getLayoutParams()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams%28%29) in Android. That method returns a [`ViewGroup.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html). The documentation for that class tells us it has a bunch of subclasses: `AbsListView.LayoutParams,` `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams`, `Gallery.LayoutParams`, `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`, `ViewPager.LayoutParams`, `WindowManager.LayoutParams`, and many more.

So, what could happen is that the *name* `LayoutParams` in the scope of the code you pasted refers to one of these subclasses. (Maybe you're inheriting `AbsListView`, or you/the IDE did an `import static` for it.) So you do in fact have to insert the cast, because the return type of `View.getLayoutParams()` isn't assignable to any of its subclasses, even if at runtime the actual value might be.

This is something mousing over the identifiers in your IDE should confirm.

As an aside: whoever designed an API that involves 10+ classes with the exact same name should be shot.

Answer (score 0):

I got your doubt now consider following exam:

```
class A
{
//assume that this class contain one method which is similar to your getLayout
public Object getObject()
{
  return new A();
}
}
```

//now first understand one thing in java that every classes in java are sub class to Object class. now look at this return stmt and method signature i.e signature is Object but we are returning A class object this is called as upcasting in java.

Next

now if we are accessing this method for A class object then we need to downcast 
i.e
A a1=(A)getObject()//getObject() method will return Object type but we are storing that object into A class object by using downcast...