# Setting LayoutParams of the LinearLayout while nested LinearLayout into RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I would like to know why a ClassCastException is thrown while I try to change the LinearLayout width and height which nested inside a RelativeLayout by code dynamically during running the program.

And more importantly, how can I solve it? I am new to java and android, please state as clear as you can. Thanks for anyone's kindly help!!!

Java File (MainActivity.java)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //To search for the LinearLayout
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        //To set new height and width of Linear Layout which is nested inside the Relative Layout
       //Even changing the class name "View Group" below to "Linear Layout" throw Class Cast Exception as well 
        ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100,200));

}
}
```

Xml File (activity_main.xml)

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
<!-- The width and height here is going to be changed by code while the program run -->
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:id="@+id/ll">
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The Exception Thrown

```
03-31 12:55:21.862: D/AndroidRuntime(734): Shutting down VM
03-31 12:55:21.862: W/dalvikvm(734): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1317)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1264)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:292)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:314)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-31 12:55:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 12:55:22.152: I/dalvikvm(734): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-31 12:55:22.162: I/dalvikvm(734): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-31 12:55:22.392: I/dalvikvm(734): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-31 12:55:22.402: I/dalvikvm(734): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-31 12:55:32.152: I/Process(734): Sending signal. PID: 734 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942415/why-does-linearlayout-instance-getlayoutparams-look-to-have-a-wrong-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the `LayoutParams` you must use is specified by the type of `Layout` that encapsulates the thing you want to change params for.

So for example if you want to change `LayoutParams` for your `LinearLayout` you need to check what's the `Layout` type that encapsulates it. In your case `LinearLayout` is being encapsulated by `RelativeLayout` so you need to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

Comment: I am sorry that I am new to stack overflow and I don't have enough reputation to vote you up, I will do it as soon as I have enough reputation.

Comment: Don't worry about that, I'm happy my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` inside `RelativeLayout` in your xml file (activity_main.xml). Use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to solve this issue.

Change this:

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100,200));
```

to:

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,200));
```